# Attach PDF and send email via Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I wrote a VBA code to send an email from a distribution list in Excel.

I want to attach a PDF. (It is one PDF on my hard drive.)

Column A is email address, column C is name, column E has the path to the PDF & cell J2 has what the body of the email will say.

How do I attach the pdf with the path in column E?

I have only 4 rows that I'm testing, however I'd like to send everything until the last row, which could vary. It's actually two macros, it would be nice if it were only one.

```
Sub SendEmail(what_address As String, subject_line As String, mail_body As String)

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    olMail.To = what_address
    olMail.Subject = subject_line
    olMail.Body = mail_body
    olMail.Send

End Sub


Sub SendMassEmail()

    row_number = 1

    Do
        DoEvents
        row_number = row_number + 1
        Dim mail_body_message As String
        Dim full_name As String
        mail_body_message = Sheet2.Range("J2")
        full_name = Sheet2.Range("c" & row_number)
        mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_name_here", full_name)
        Call SendEmail(Sheet2.Range("A" & row_number), "Request for Tax Exemption Certificate", mail_body_message)
    Loop Until row_number = 4

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that everything else in the code is working as expected. Then, you would need to add the following line before the `olMail.Send` method. Example:

```
olMail.attachments.Add Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2").Value, olByValue, , "sampleFile"
```

More information on the attachments.add method can be found here [Attachments Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add)

The send mail function would look like this :

```
Sub SendEmail(what_address As String, subject_line As String, mail_body As String)

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

olMail.To = what_address
olMail.Subject = subject_line
olMail.Body = mail_body
olMail.attachments.Add Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2").Value, olByValue, , "sampleFile"
olMail.Send

End Sub
```

Edit 1: I guess your question was how to include multiple attachments into an email. Then you can try this :

```
Sub SendEmail(what_address As String, subject_line As String, mail_body As String)

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim lastRow As Integer

Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'Provide the Column where the attachment links are stored. I guess its E in your case
lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

olMail.To = what_address
olMail.Subject = subject_line
olMail.Body = mail_body

'Loop through the column and add the attachments to the Email
For i = 2 To lastRow
    .attachments.Add Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & i).Value, olByValue
Next i
olMail.Send

End Sub
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you so much! What do i need to add for it to loop to the end and not just those 3 rows?

Comment: ‘i=2’ The loop starts picking data from the second row. Assuming that the first row is filled with headers.